# How can I get application installation path on Mac?(Java)

Tags: java, macos, path

This is how I get installation path on Windows:
`String workingDirectory = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");`
On Mac it just gives me user directory not application installation path, how can i get application installation path on Mac.

Comment: Can you set an example of application installation path?

Comment: See if this works for you: `URL url = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I did do this, it returns jar location, if there is no way to get the installation path, I will use this method.

Comment: @triffic like this `/Applications/AppName`